# How to prevent using relative paths require beyond the package in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, requirejs, node-modules

Let's say the project has 2 packages on the same level:

- package1

  - app

    - test1.js
  - package.json
- package2

  - app

    - test2.js
  - package.json

I would like to prevent any relative path imports of "package2 files" inside package1 and vise versa. For example disallow import require(../../package2/app/test2.js) inside package1/app/test1.js.

We could write some static analyzer to make such check, but wonder if there are any existing tools to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a code smell, and suggests that your two packages are indeed not self contained.  The proper way to handle cross package dependencies is to publish `package1` and include it in the dependencies of `package2`, and make it available to `package2` by running `npm install` in its directory.

While developing these two packages, you can avoid publishing your modules by running `npm link` in `package1`'s directory to make it available in the global package cache, and to make it available to `package2`, you can run `npm link package1` from `package2`'s directory.

Comment: Hi ctt, thanks for the response. Sure, there is a better way how to structure packages and manage dependencies. The question is how to prevent the bad way?

Comment: To prevent the bad way, you should ensure that use of `require(..)` to reach outside of a package uses the commonjs search path.  Providing relative paths to `require()` that walk up the directory tree will render the package unusable by any developer who doesn't share your exact development setup.  The intent is for packages to be consumed by simply `npm install`-ing them.

Comment: Thanks ctt! Does it mean there are some settings I could tweak to setup development in specific way? Could you please pinpoint me to any example if you have?


Disclaimer: I'm super new to Node.js. Unfortunately, our projects are heavy using relative imports going outside of their the scope, so we would like to add hard fails checks (automation) in addition to code reviews.